# Using in_array with a Serialized array?

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have a serialized value in my mysql db that looks like this:

```
a:5:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Keith Donegan";s:3:"age";s:2:"21";s:7:"college";s:9:"Spin City";s:8:"category";s:1:"7";s:8:"checkbox";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"3";i:1;s:1:"9";}}
```

I can output the checkbox array fine, but I need to run it againest another set of ids using in_array but my code doesn't work, surprise! :)

```
echo $eirepanel_general_options['checkbox']; // used in a foreach loop
```

See the values 3 & 9, I need to test these.

---

**EDIT: MAIN Code**

```
<?php

$eirepanel_general_options_saved = $_REQUEST['eirepanel_general_options_saved'];
if(isset($eirepanel_general_options_saved))
{
    $eirepanel_general_options_name = $_REQUEST['eirepanel_general_options_name'];
    $eirepanel_general_options_age = $_REQUEST['eirepanel_general_options_age'];
    $eirepanel_general_options_college = $_REQUEST['eirepanel_general_options_college'];
    $eirepanel_general_options_category = $_REQUEST['eirepanel_general_options_category'];
    $eirepanel_general_options_checkbox = $_REQUEST['eirepanel_general_options_checkbox'];

    $eirepanel_general_options = array
    (
    'name' => $eirepanel_general_options_name,
    'age' => $eirepanel_general_options_age,
    'college' => $eirepanel_general_options_college,
    'category' => $eirepanel_general_options_category,
    'checkbox' => $eirepanel_general_options_checkbox
    );

    update_option('eirepanel_general_options', $eirepanel_general_options);
}
else
{
$eirepanel_general_options = get_option('eirepanel_general_options');
}


$categories = get_categories(); 
foreach($categories as $category)
{ 
    $eirepanel_general_options_string = $eirepanel_general_options['checkbox'];
    $eirepanel_general_options_array = explode(',', $eirepanel_general_options_string);
    echo$cat_ids = explode(',',$category->cat_ID);

    $ids = array(8, 4);

    var_dump($eirepanel_general_options_string);

    ?>


    <?php // <input name="eirepanel_general_options_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>
        <?php // if($eirepanel_general_options_string == $category->cat_ID ){ echo "checked='checked'"; } <br /> ?>

        <span><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></span>
        <input name="eirepanel_general_options_checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>" type="checkbox" <?php in_array($eirepanel_general_options_string, $ids) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> /> <br />

<?php }

// var_dump($eirepanel_general_options_string);


?>
```

Comment: Why don't you unserialize the array first to use in_array? I don't see the problem.

Comment: Why do you declare variables only to pass them into an array?

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what your expected outcome is, and what your actual outcome is. Which bit is broken?

Answer (score 3):

[unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) is your friend here!!

run the string containing the array through that function, catch the result and work with that.

```
$serial = **serial array goes here**;
$array = unserialize($serial);
```

Then

```
echo $array['checkbox'];
```

would function as you would expect.

Use [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to reverse the effects, if needed.

```
$serial = serialize($array);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I am using Wordpress and this does this already I assume

Comment: @KeithDonegan what does the value look like if you `var_dump()` it right before using `in_array()`? That way you can be sure if Wordpress is indeed doing what you expect.

Comment: does what already? It will serialize an array when storing it in the database (I think this may be mySQL doing the leg work here, but I could be wrong).

Comment: @Treffynnon array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "7" [1]=> string(1) "6" } thanks

Comment: well then it is already a standard array, your problem seems to be that you are calling an string based key, when they are stored numerically.

Comment: I think you need to put a lot more code in your question for us to really see what the issue is.

Comment: @KeithDonegan That array is also completely different to the one you have shown in serialised form in your question.

Comment: Thanks Mild Fuzz, I am testing against: $ids = array'8,4);

Answer (score 0):

A serialised array is no longer an array but a string export of the array values.
To use array functions, you need to return it to an array using unserialize(), then it is an array which you can treat like an array else, it is just a string.